Using MUI icons in react with class="material-symbols-outlined"
I am trying to include the MUI icons in my code with the following syntax as mentioned here:
<span className="material-symbols-outlined">
menu
</span>

However, it gets displayed as plaintext menu instead of the menu icon. I also tried this as mentioned here:
import Icon from '@mui/material/Icon';
...
<Icon>terminal</Icon>

but this displays it as plaintext too.
This works:
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
...
<MenuIcon />

But I want to dynamically load the icons, so this way does not work for me.
I have the icons in a JSON file, and different items have different icons. Depending on the item that is loaded, the icon changes.
Any ideas on how to make this work?

I suggest you to use Iconify
This lib has all possible icons, a good integration with MUI and the able to import icons dynamically, like:
import { Icon } from '@iconify/react';

<Icon icon='mdi:edit'/>

